# How to move my old file from a datagrid cell to a different folder

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagrid

I need to move my file in cell[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAott.jpg) to a folder called `@"C:\user\Archieve"` and replace that file with new file from cell[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnbYn.jpg). So currently
i am able to move file from cell[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnbYn.jpg) to cell[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAott.jpg). If i need to replace a file from cell[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnbYn.jpg) to cell[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAott.jpg). I need the file which is already in cell[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAott.jpg)
to be moved to `@"C:\user\Archieve"`, and then file from cell[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnbYn.jpg) to be replace in the cell[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAott.jpg) and with a new location of `@"C:\user\release"`.
How can i do this. I have done the first part which is working perfectly.

i need to do the second part. Please help me guys??

Link to my cell view [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnbYn.jpg)

[image]

Link to my flow chart [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAott.jpg)

[image]

Code snippet:

```
   private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string copyPath = @"C:\user\release";
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(copyPath))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(copyPath);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) &&                 
(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString())))
            {
                string filePath = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(copyPath, fileName);
                    System.IO.File.Move(filePath, newpath);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = newpath;

                    try
                    { 
                      ///codes to update in databse
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = string.Empty;
            }

            else if ((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString())) &&
(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString())))
            {
                //This part will move the file into Archieve folder if the file exist in Cell 3
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != null)
                {
                    string archievePath = @"C:\user\Archieve\";
                    string fileName = archievePath + Path.GetFileName(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                    System.IO.File.Move(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), fileName);
                }

                //Now you can continue the process as it was.
                //Move the file from Cell2 to Cell3 directly.
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != null)
                {
                    //you can change this line to your old logic to generate the new file name.
                    string releasePath = @"C:\user\release\";
                    string newfileName = releasePath + Path.GetFileName(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                    System.IO.File.Move(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), newfileName);

                    //Delete the file from old location if exist
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()))
                        System.IO.File.Delete(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());

                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = newfileName;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = string.Empty;
                }
            }
    }

private void Update_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=stacy3422\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update cncinfo set part='" + this.file_NameTextBox.Text
                + "',drawings='" + this.drawingsTextBox.Text + "',draftpath='"
                + this.gcodeTextBox.Text + "',comments='" + this.commentsTextBox.Text
                + "' where part='" + partKey + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            this.Validate();
            load_table();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You really need to describe your proposed work flow and questions more logically. What you want to do first, what next. Where the current problem is.

Comment: @TianyunLing Link to my floc chart : -https://imageshack.com/i/p26HMK7Sj

Comment: So in the `else` clause you `Move` the file, save the `newpath` in the grid, then do the _same_ file `Move` again. What is the exact error message?

Comment: @HABBO I dont know how to move the file from cell[2] to location -`@"C:\user\Archieve"` and replace the cell[2] with cell[1] file. pleasee see this link for my flowchart imageshack.com/i/p26HMK7Sj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im just giving you a logic. You can add more condition later.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //This part will move the file into Archieve folder if the file exist in Cell 2
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != null)
    {
         string archievePath = @"C:\user\Archieve\";
         string fileName = archievePath  + Path.GetFileName(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
         System.IO.File.Move(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), fileName);
    }

    //Now you can continue the process as it was.
    //Move the file from Cell1 to Cell2 directly.
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)
    {
         //you can change this line to your old logic to generate the new file name.
         string releasePath = @"C:\user\release\";
         string newfileName = releasePath + Path.GetFileName(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
         System.IO.File.Move(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), newfileName );

         //Delete the file from old location if exist
         if (System.IO.File.Exist(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
              System.IO.File.Delete(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()));

         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = newfileName;
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of the things is working well untill i make the thrid update of file to cell[2].
For first time its working well [moving file from cell[2] to cell[3] and reset's the cell[2], second time aslo working well.
[i mean the file is moved from cell[3] archieve and cell[2] to cell[3]. But when comes to updates again a file into cell[2]. When i press the
database updatebutton[in datagridview] the old file is automatically changing to the initial file name..
Please see the link for a diagramatic view. https://imageshack.com/i/iqZbuhxtj

Comment: When ever i change the same file(sample) from folder"C:\user\fab".(lets say i changed the file name from (sample) to (sample1).. 
automatically update the file(sample2) name to cell[0] and update in database too. 
automatically attach the same file(sample2) to cell[2] and update in database too. 

when ever i change the contents of file(sample/sample2/or any) from folder"C:\user\fab" 
automatically update the file(sample/sample2/or any) name to cell[0] and update in database too. 
automatically attach the same file(sample2) to cell[2] and update in database too.

Comment: when ever i delete the file(sample/sample2/or any) from folder"C:\user\fab" 
automatically delete the file(sample/sample2/or any) name to cell[0] and update in database too. 
automatically delete the same file(sample/sample2/or any) to cell[2] and update in database too.

So i can make a different application that runs in background right.. and it does all the job and update in database. is that the good way.. 
or i should incorporate the automatic updation coding..in my same application..

Comment: My most important thing is my application should be ideal and doesnot use more memmory. and it should only update the entire thing.. i mean 
database on every day morning 11 o clock and evening 3:30 p.m.. can you help me.. pleasee 
Can you help me with this.. this is my final.. thing for assignment.. so that i can finish the project..

Answer (score 0):

So when the operation is done, Cell1 must be cleared and Cell2 must contain the 'Release' path, if I understand correctly. Here's your new 'else block':

```
string filePath = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
  // First move the Cell2 file to 'Archieve'
  string replacepath = @"C:\user\Archieve";
  string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
  string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(replacepath, fileName);
  System.IO.File.Move(filePath, newpath);

  // Then moving Cell1 file to 'Release', replace Cell2 and clear Cell1
  string filePath2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath2))
  {
    string fileName2 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath2);
    string newpath2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(copyPath, fileName2);
    System.IO.File.Move(filePath2, newpath2);
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = newpath2;
    try
    { 
      ///codes to update in databse
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
  }
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = string.Empty;
}
```

Obviously, in order to clean the code, a method should be extracted to move files and update the datagrid accordingly.

Comment: that was a perfect one.. but the thing. The first time it moved the file from cell[2] to new location and placed the new file from cell[1] to cell[2]. Again when i updated a third file to cell[1]. its not doing.. :-(

Comment: Also in the above code its showing an error.. `Error 2 A local variable named 'fileName' and 'newpath' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'fileName' and 'newpath', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

Comment: may be i guess when i am trying for the third replace,, this is the reason i guess its not replacing

Comment: Ok i understood why the second time when i am uploading a file its not moving to the archieve folder.. its because of my database update.. the moment when i update the third file.. in cell[2] its automatically going to the old location.. ANy ways to edit this.. i have updated my database update.. code...

Comment: @Stacy Kebler for the compile error, you just need to rename these variables (scope problem, the same names are used above). See my updated code.

Comment: Both of the things is working well untill i make the thrid update of file to cell[2].
For first time its working well [moving file from cell[2] to cell[3] and reset's the cell[2], second time aslo working well.
[i mean the file is moved from cell[3] archieve and cell[2] to cell[3]. But when comes to updates again a file into cell[2]. When i press the
database updatebutton[in datagridview] the old file is automatically changing to the initial file name..
Please see the link for a diagramatic view. https://imageshack.com/i/iqZbuhxtj